# Jackson dependency in maven and developing in eclipse with JBoss EAP 6.3/6.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I'm using eclipse and developing some services with resteasy with jackson as json provider:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Those libs are actually supplied to the build path via `JBoss EAP 6.1+ runtime`. But I've to set some jackson specific options via a custom `ObjectMapper`. For this I added another dependency on jackson:

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now this breaks my eclipse build because the server runtime only includes ee libs. Of course I can change the scope but that results in the artifact being included in the final war even if it's already packaged as a jboss module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to JBoss Tools to 4.3 and adding `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` did the trick:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" export="true" />
         <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" export="true" />
         <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" export="true" />        
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```